# A video with $30$ minutes length, played at $33.33\%$ faster speed that equates to $22.5$ minutes. Where are the extra $2.508$ minutes?

Tags: arithmetic

> A video with $30$ minutes length, played at $33.33\%$ faster speed that equates to $22.5$ minutes. Where are the extra $2.508$ minutes?

Yes the math is $$\frac{30}{1.3333} = 22.50,$$
but my intuition is that the result should be $20$ minutes.  How do we reconcile that "$2.5$" minutes extra?

Comment: Why "intuitively" should the answer be $20$ minutes?

Comment: Let's go through a simpler example. Let's say that the video is played at $100\%$ faster speed, i.e. $2 \times$ speed. Then I think there's no intuitive issue concluding the video is

$$\frac{30 \text{ min.}}{2} = 15 \text{ min.}$$

long. So what if the video is $30\%$ faster, i.e. $1.3 \times$ speed? The same sort of calculation gives its length as

$$\frac{30 \text{ min.}}{1.3} \approx 23.077 \text{ min.}$$

Comment: On the other hand, this begs a question: at what speed we will play the video at to get $20$ minutes? If we set up the proportion, we see

$$\frac{30 \text{ min.}}{x} = 20 \text{ min.} \implies x = \frac{30 \text{ min.}}{20 \text{ min.}} = 1.5$$

i.e. the video would have to be played $50\%$ faster. I don't really see how this is unintuitive.

Comment: Why the downvotes? OP shared reasoning and steps taken, even if flawed. Isn't that the point of asking?

Comment: @ David G. Stork, "intuitively" because if the video is 30 mins long and it played a third faster.  Therefore the last third of video would have been negate due to faster speed.  So  only 20 mins would have get accounted.

Comment: @DreiCleaner: Look at the revision history. Don't assume that downvoters have no good reason. (By the way I wasn't even one of them.)

Answer (score 6):

You have two problems.  I think you are trying to say that if it is played $\frac 13$ faster you expect it to be done in $20$ minutes.  First, $\frac 13$ faster is $33.3\overline 3\%$ faster, not $30\%$ faster.  That would make the running time $\dfrac {30}{\frac43}=22.5$ minutes.  The second is that if you want to reduce the running time from $30$ to $20$ minutes, you need to go $50\%$ faster.  As you are reducing the time by a factor $\frac 23$ you need to increase the speed by a factor $\frac 32$